# Como adicionar um valor que calculei a partir de um dado informado aparecer num novo TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, textview

Preciso calcular a frequência cardíaca máxima a partir da idade informada pelo usuário (fcm = 220 - idade). Criei os campos para capturar o nome e a idade, mas não consigo fazer com que a fcm calculada apareça na tela. As informações de nome e fcm devem aparecer numa lista rolável. Já fiz tantas alterações que criei algum erro em que o app fecha ao clicar no botão... Enfim, em uma classe Atleta peguei a idade, converti para int e calculei fcm. No Main, não sei como pegar a fcm calculada e lançar no método que processa o clique. Mesma coisa no meu adapter: como fcm não é um TextView, não sei como tratar isso.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txtNome, txtIdade;
    Button bt;
    ListView listAtletas;
    List<Atleta> atletas = new ArrayList<>();
    AtletaAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtNome = findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
        txtIdade = findViewById(R.id.txtIdade);
        bt = findViewById(R.id.bt);
        bt.setOnClickListener(btClickListener);
        listAtletas = findViewById(R.id.listAtleta);
        adapter = new AtletaAdapter(atletas, getBaseContext());
        listAtletas.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void processarClique(View v) {
        Atleta a = new Atleta();
        a.setNome((txtNome.getText().toString()));
        ??????????????????

        atletas.add(a);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    View.OnClickListener btClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            processarClique(v);
        }
    };
}



public class Atleta {
    private String nome;
    TextView txtIdade;

    private int idade = Integer.parseInt(txtIdade.getText().toString());
    private int fcm = 220 - idade;

    public void setNome(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public void setFcm(int fcm){
        this.fcm = fcm;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public int getFcm(){
        return fcm;
    }
}



public class AtletaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Atleta> atletas;

    public AtletaAdapter(List<Atleta> atletas, Context ctx){
        this.atletas = atletas;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return atletas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return atletas.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.atleta_item, null);
        TextView txtNome = v.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeItem);
        ??????????????

        Atleta a = atletas.get(position);
        txtNome.setText(a.getNome());
        ??????????????????
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está sua resposta. Tende entender tudo que eu fiz.

MVC CHORA AO VER ISTO [O que é mvc.](https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/o-que-e-mvc/)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText txtNome, txtIdade, txtFrequenciaCardiaca;
Button bt;
ListView listAtletas;
List<Atleta> atletas = new ArrayList<>();
AtletaAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtNome = findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
    txtIdade = findViewById(R.id.txtIdade);
    txtFrequenciaCardiaca = findViewById(R.id.txtFrequenciaCardiaca);

    bt = findViewById(R.id.bt);
    bt.setOnClickListener(btClickListener);
    listAtletas = findViewById(R.id.listAtleta);
    adapter = new AtletaAdapter(atletas, this);
    listAtletas.setAdapter(adapter);
}

View.OnClickListener btClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Atleta a = new Atleta();
        a.setNome((txtNome.getText().toString()));

        String idade = txtIdade.getText().toString();

        if (idade.equals("")) {
            //ele nao pode deixar sem idade
            return;
        }

        a.setIdade(Integer.parseInt(idade));

        String fcm = txtFrequenciaCardiaca.getText().toString();

        if (fcm.equals("")) {
            //ele nao pode deixar sem frequencia cardiaca atual
            return;
        }

        a.setFcm(Integer.parseInt(fcm));

        atletas.add(a);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        
        //para limpar os campos
        txtNome.setText("");
        txtIdade.setText("");
        txtFrequenciaCardiaca.setText("");
    }
};
}

class Atleta {
private String nome;
private int idade;
private int fcm;

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public int getIdade() {
    return idade;
}

public void setIdade(int idade) {
    this.idade = idade;
}

public int getFcm() {
    return fcm;
}

public void setFcm(int fcm) {
    this.fcm = fcm;
}

public int frequenciaMaximaCardiaca() {
    return 200 - idade;
}

public String resultadoFrequencia() {
    if (getFcm() > frequenciaMaximaCardiaca()) {
        return "Cuidado frequencia cardiaca muito alta";
    } else {
        return "Faça ele correr mais";
    }
}
}

class AtletaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
LayoutInflater inflater;
//os dados serao obtidos pela lista e nao direto ao edittext
List<Atleta> atletas;
//tem que criar separados
TextView txtNomeItem, txtIdadeItem, txtFrequenciaItem, txtFrequenciaMaximaItem, txtResultadoItem;

public AtletaAdapter(List<Atleta> atletas, Context ctx) {
    this.atletas = atletas;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return atletas.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return atletas.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.atleta_item, null);
    txtNomeItem = v.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeItem);
    txtIdadeItem = v.findViewById(R.id.txtIdadeItem);
    txtFrequenciaItem = v.findViewById(R.id.txtFrequenciaAtualItem);
    txtFrequenciaMaximaItem = v.findViewById(R.id.txtFrequenciaMaximaItem);
    txtResultadoItem = v.findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);

    Atleta atleta = atletas.get(position);

    txtNomeItem.setText(atleta.getNome());
    //se torna obrigado a converter em string porque se nao ele achara que é um objeto da memoria
    txtIdadeItem.setText(String.valueOf(atleta.getIdade()));
    txtFrequenciaItem.setText(String.valueOf(atleta.getFcm()));
    txtResultadoItem.setText(atleta.resultadoFrequencia());

    return v;
}
}
```

Layout main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtNome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Nome:"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtIdade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Idade:"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtFrequenciaCardiaca"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Frequencia cardiaca:"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Calcular"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listAtleta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout alteta_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtNomeItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtIdadeItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFrequenciaMaximaItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFrequenciaAtualItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtResultado"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```